# Ubuntu uses a screen resolution lower than my laptop can support

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, resolution, display-settings

I have installed ubuntu 9.10 on my laptop.

In System->Display, the best resolution I allow me to use is 1280x700. But my laptop can support 1600x900.

So how can i change it?
I tried adding

```
xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00" 118.25 1600 1696 1856 2112 900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
```

and in /etc/gdm/Init/Default

But that does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem in the past as well.  To fix it I just had to install some display drivers.  To do this go to System —> Administration —> Hardware Drivers and see if there are any display drivers to activate.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem with an old Dell Latitude C600, and found [this link](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/fix-for-video-problem-on-the-dell-latitude-c600c500.html) to be the solution, so a similar method with different numbers in the resolution section would probably work. It didn't automatically use the native resolution after a reboot, but the option did then appear in the Display settings dialog.